# Sed bash script iterating multiple times

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I have an assignment of editing a text file, called `LOLOLOL`.

```
HRFJGEKGJHEJGKJVNEJGKJEG BOB BO B

GARY gARY gARY gary

FOG GARY bob bob bob Gary gary

the the bird in the the bush!

LOL MATE!
```

I have a bash script file called `lolz.script`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '1i Hee hee hee\n Ho Ho Ho\n' $1
sed 's/bob/Bob/g' $1
```

running `.\lolz.script LOLOLOL` at the command line, I get multiple iterations of the `LOLOLOL` text- precisely, one iteration per sed command.

For example, the output shows the first and second sed commands (applied for each) here:

```
*Hee Hee Hee 
Ho Ho Ho*
HRFJGEKGJHEJGKJVNEJGKJEG BOB BO B

GARY gARY gARY gary

FOG GARY bob bob bob Gary gary

the the bird in the the bush!

LOL MATE!
HRFJGEKGJHEJGKJVNEJGKJEG BOB BO B

GARY gARY gARY gary

FOG GARY *Bob Bob Bob* Gary gary

the the bird in the the bush!

LOL MATE!
```

- --- * show the changed part of the text file in the output.

Whereas what I want output:

```
*Hee Hee Hee 
Ho Ho Ho*
HRFJGEKGJHEJGKJVNEJGKJEG BOB BO B

GARY gARY gARY gary

FOG GARY Bob Bob Bob Gary gary

the the bird in the the bush!

LOL MATE!
```

As you can see, each sed command is applied *independently* in each iteration of printing the text file. I need all sed commands to be applied *together*.

Note how the desired header from the first sed command is applied in the first iteration, while in the second it is not (but the `bob` to `Bob` change is).

Why has this happened, and what can I do to make commands in a script cumulative to one text file? This didn't seem to happen with same-format `awk` script.

Answer (score 2):

Simply: you are invoking `sed` twice.

If you run those commands in a terminal one after the other, you will end up with two sets of output. Your script is just doing the same thing in its own shell.

You can use `{}` to group commands and put each one on a new line or use `;` so all the commands act on the file cumulatively, calling sed only once:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '{
     1i Hee hee hee\n Ho Ho Ho\n
     s/bob/Bob/g
}' "$1"
```

output of `./script file`

```
Hee hee hee
 Ho Ho Ho

HRFJGEKGJHEJGKJVNEJGKJEG BOB BO B

GARY gARY gARY gary

FOG GARY Bob Bob Bob Gary gary

the the bird in the the bush!

LOL MATE!
```